# trying to understand how to prove statement in the form of $p\implies q\vee r$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I am confused about how we can prove the statement in the form of

$$p\implies q\vee r $$

Can we prove it by showing one of $q$
, $r$ is true and since the statement is $q\vee r$ this mean it is true and the proof ends?

For example

In this theorem in linear algebra

if $ku=O$ , then $k=0$ or $u=O$

to prove this the book assumes
two possibilities (1) if $k=0$ (2) if $k\neq0$

My question is why don't we just show one possibility when $k=0$ and when we prove it is true the proof is ended since we have "or" statement? or do we have to show all the possibilities that make the $q\vee r$ true?

Comment: Because you *CAN'T* prove $k=0$.  It might not be true.  What if $ku=0; k= 237; u = 0$?  The book isn't assuming two possibitiies; the book *knows* two possibilities.  The book knows that either $k =0$ or $k \ne 0$.  But the book doesn't know which one.

Comment: "Can we prove it by showing one of q , r is true and since the statement is q∨r this mean it is true and the proof ends?"  You *can* IF you can.  But what if you can't prove *either* p nor q.   If the *only* thing you know is that $ku =0$ there is no way in the world that you will ever be able to prove $k=0$ because it might not be true.  Nor could you ever prove $u=0$ because it might not be true.  But you can prove that if the only thing you know is $ku =0$ you *can* prove that EITHER $k=0$ or $u=0$ but you can't ever know which one (or both) is true.

Comment: No, you don't need to consider all cases. These proofs are standard. They usually start by saying, "If  q is true then we are done. If not ..." where we then go on to show that $r$ must be true.

Comment: You may prove that $p\land\lnot q\land\lnot r$ is false.